# VS 2008 vs VS 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008 at work to do web development.  I've gotten quite used to it but can't really afford to purchase even VS 2008 Standard at this time.

I have never used any of the Express editions before but I was thinking about downloading VS C# Express and VS Web Developer Express.

Am I wasting my time or can I do some serious development with these tools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do serious development on the express editions. They have taken out a few things most notably the plug in system. If you are use to using a bunch of plug ins you may find that not being able to use them is a deterrent.

Here is a link to a comparison of the express edition and the other editions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbsd3cz(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Note that VC# is much more (functionally) limited than VC++.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed do serious development using the Visual Studio 2008 express editions, this includes commercial products see question number 7 in the [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc149003.aspx) which says:

> Seven) Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
>   Yes, there are no
>   licensing restrictions for
>   applications built using Visual Studio
>   Express Editions.

The [feature matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc149003.aspx) shows that whilst you do lose some functionality between the Pro and Express Editions.  The single biggest issue being that there is no add-in support (and adding it is forbidden by the EULA) which limits many nice additions to the environment such as ReSharper, VisualAssist, etc.

You also don't get a "Studio" but four individual editions, Web Developer, VB, VC++ and C#, if you wish to mix and match languages/projects in the way that the Standard/Professional Editions support then you are out of luck.  Under the surface however, MSBuild is available and can provide you with multi-language solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Express Editions works fine if you do not want to have different project types/languages in a solution, and you have no need for builtin source control.

Else, it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed list of available features on different editions of Visual Studio : [Product Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc149003.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a comparison of the features in the various editions of Visual Studio 2008 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en). The things that I find most annoying about the express edition are that you can't have multiple projects in a solution file, and you can't use add-ons like Resharper.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you define "serious development".  One big thing missing from the express (and even standard) editions is the lack of support for mobile development.  You also miss the convenience of grouping different project types in a solution.

I think you also miss some of the project types (windows services, Sql Server/CLR projects come to mind) in the Express edition.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't afforded the full version of VS2008 at home yet so I have Express and use it for some intermediate application development (no web stuff). I find it quite good enough, it's got most of the stuff I use. I tried SharpDevelop but it wouldn't allow more than one start up project so I ditched it for Express.

Most plugins don't seem to work in the Express versions if that's an issue for you.

Comment: Plug-ins should not work in the Express Editions as Microsoft forbid their use and have deliberately broken the support for them.  It's still there however, Google "TestDriven.NET express EULA" for a link to a case where Microsoft went in heavy against someone who worked out a way around the limits!

Answer (score 1):

You actually CAN do commercial work with the VS 2008 Express editions.

See the answer to question #7 of the FAQ at this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Professional version of VS2008 for free (if you have a .edu address) via [Microsoft Dreamspark](https://downloads.channel8.msdn.com/).

For that matter, the (fully-functional) 90-day trial of both VS2005 and VS2008 Pro... can be "extended"... indefinitely... by setting your system clock back, but no real reason to do that.

Express is fine for being a "lite" version but is hobbled in all sorts of ways. For anything serious, get the real thing.

Comment: The original poster said he was employed and I think using the .Edu version without actually being a student/teacher would be in breach of the conditions.  True there is a time bombed demo, but that's only going to be useful for evaluation not long term use!

Answer (score 1):

I do serious work using the Express editions. I'm not a professional programmer since I moved into management, but I still keep my hand in writing the occasional utility or web page. The only thing I've missed from the professional versions is remote web debugging.